# Using an index in MySQL JOIN with OR condition

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm running a query which looks like this

```
SELECT parent.field, child.field
FROM parent
JOIN child ON (child.id = parent.id 
    OR child.id = parent.otherid)
```

This is however really slow (about 100k records, and JOINs to other tables in the real version), but despite having tried indexes on

```
parent.id (PRIMARY),  
parent.otherid,  
child.id (PRIMARY), 
and a composite index of parent.id and parent.otherid
```

I cannot get MySQL to use any of those indexes when making this join.

I read that MySQL can use only one index per join, but can't find anywhere whether it can use a composite index when a JOIN contains an OR condition.

Does anyone here know if it's possible to make this query reference an index?
If so, how?

---

MY SOLUTION

(SO won't let me answer my own question below atm)

A bunch of tweaking and came up with a fairly decent solution which retains the ability to JOIN and aggregate other tables.

```
SELECT parent.field, child.field
FROM parent
JOIN (
    SELECT parent.id as parentid, 
    # Prevents the need to union
    IF(NOT ISNULL(parent.otherid) AND parent.otherid <> parent.id, 
       parent.otherid, 
       parent.id) as getdataforid
    FROM parent
    WHERE (condition)
) as foundrecords
    ON foundrecords.parentid = parent.id
JOIN child ON child.id = parent.getdataforid
```

For speed requires a condition inside the subquery to reduce the number of records placed in a temporary table, but I have tons of additional joins on the outer query, some joining to the child and some to the parent (with some aggregates) so this one worked best for me.

In many cases a union will be faster and more effective, but since I'm filtering on parent, but want additional data from child (parent self-references), the union caused extra rows for me which I couldn't consolidate.
It's possible the same result can be found just by joining parent to itself and aliasing a where condition in the outer query, but this one works quite nicely for me.

Thanks to Jirka for the UNION ALL suggestion, it's what prompted me to get here :)

Comment: Did you run `explain select ...` on the query?

Comment: yep, the explain is what's letting me know it's not using any indexes for this join.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your query makes it theoretically possible that a single child has two distinct parents, which would make it for quite nonstandard terminology.  Let's however assume that your data patterns make that impossible.

Then the following gives you the same result using separate indexes, one index per column.

```
SELECT parent.field, child.field
FROM parent
JOIN child ON child.id = parent.id 

UNION ALL

SELECT parent.field, child.field
FROM parent
JOIN child ON child.id = parent.otherid
```

Comment: +1.  excatly what I would suggest trying, breaking this into two separate queries, and combining the results, although this query COULD return more rows than the original query.  (Consider a row in parent where id = otherid). To guarantee the same results, add the predicate `AND parent.otherid <> parent.id` on that second query. (NULLs aren't an issue in that test, since parent.id is NOT NULL by virtue of it being PRIMARY KEY.)

Comment: This is an excellent solution in the simplified case (thanks), but it prevents aggregation of data in child (using GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT child.field)). Playing with the idea though to see if I can apply it to speed up similar queries but without the aggregation. Thanks :D

Comment: @BobDavies - You can.  Embed this as a subquery.

Comment: While this answer (and the other) assume that this is joining tables within a model, it's also entirely possible to encounter this scenario while running analytical queries where each of a set of values is used in multiple contexts, such as rollups, and so this answer doesn't really help unless you can split them into exclusive contexts (which isn't what you want with e.g. rollups).

Comment: @bsplosion - That's true.  Feel free to add a CTE based solution as another answer.  Or post a question with details of what you have tried if you are closer to that situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT parent.fld, child.fld 
  FROM parent JOIN child ON child.id = parent.id  
 UNION ALL 
SELECT parent.fld, child.fld
  FROM parent JOIN child ON child.id = parent.otherid
   AND parent.otherid <> parent.id
```

with tables using MyISAM engine:

```
id  select_type   TABLE       TYPE    possible_keys  KEY      key_len  ref                  ROWS  Extra
1   PRIMARY       parent      ALL     PRIMARY                                               9999
1   PRIMARY       child       eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4        test.parent.id       1
2   UNION         parent      ALL     parent_ix1                                            9999  USING WHERE
2   UNION         child       eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4        test.parent.otherid  1
    UNION RESULT  <union1,2>  ALL
```

with tables using InnoDB engine:

```
id  select_type   table       type    possible_keys  key         key_len  ref            rows  Extra
1   PRIMARY       child       ALL     PRIMARY                                            9903
1   PRIMARY       parent      eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY     4        test.child.id  1
2   UNION         child       ALL     PRIMARY                                            9903
2   UNION         parent      ref     parent_ix1     parent_ix1  5        test.child.id  1     Using where
    UNION RESULT  <union1,2>  ALL
```